# How can I define additional parameters in jenkinsfile who inherit from a pipeline shared lib?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I would like to add a possibility to extends the global parameters define in a Jenkins pipeline. Each JenkinsFile who call the default pipeline have default parameters and he as able to define parameters himself like this:

```groovy
@Library('mylib') _ 
generic_pipeline {

 parameters {
            choice(choices: namespaces, description: 'namespaces ?', name: 'namespaceIdChoice')
            string(defaultValue: "$BRANCH_NAME-$BUILD_NUMBER", description: 'What is the project name ?', name: 'projectName')
            }

}
```

my generic_pipeline is define in a shared lib generic_pipeline.groovy
and they have already default parameters like this:

```groovy
def call(Closure body) {
    def params = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = params
    body()


    pipeline {

        agent {
            label 'master'
        }

        parameters {
            string(defaultValue: "defaultParam2", description: 'What is defaultParam2 ?', name: 'defaultParam2')
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do that ? how can I define additional parameters for the inheritances ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

We have a separate jobParams.groovy under /vars that sets common params

```
List commonParams() {
     //return list of parameters
     def paramsList = [
         choice(name: 'ACCOUNT_NAME', choices: ['account1', 'account2'].join('\n'),  description: 'Account Name'),
         choice(name: 'AWS_REGION', choices: PipelineUtils.regions.join('\n'), description: 'AWS Region to build/deploy'),
    ]

     return paramsList
}
```

Then in your Jenkinsfile, just concatenate the list with the specifics:

```
List commonParams = jobParams.commonParams()
properties([
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '20')),
        parameters([
            choice(name: 'MY_SPECIFIC_PARAM', choices: ['1', '2', '3'].join('\n'), description: ''),
            choice(name: 'PARAM2', choices: ['value'].join('\n'), description: ''),
        ] + commonParams)
    ])
```

Comment: I am very new to pipeline, how do we access the specific list values defined in shared lib?, `println commonParams.ACCOUNT_NAME` or `println "${commonParams.ACCOUNT_NAME}` don't work, any help? thanks.

Comment: So this is returning a list of choices, which you append to the existing list of choices.

To access it would be params.ACCOUNT_NAME, because once the job executes, they look like they were defined together. The fact you sourced the list from the shared lib isn't relevant